# type mismatch when referencing value of cells to values in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete entire row if value in column B (sheet "Track") is the same as value in column B (sheet "Active"). 
But run time error 13 (type mismatch) always occur even though both values I refer are string type

Here is the code:

```
Sub delete_row()
Dim active As Worksheet: Set activeSH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Active")
Dim Tracksheet As Worksheet: Set KPI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Track")
Dim i As Integer
Dim name As String

    With Tracksheet
         For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 4 Step -1
         name = .Range("B" & i).Value 

            'Here I loop through each value in col B of Track sheet 
            'and reference it to values in col B of sheet "active"       
            If name = active.Range("B:B").Value Then 'this line where run time error 13 (type mismatch occurs)

                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

            Else
            End If
        i = i - 1
        Next i
    End With
 End Sub
```

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: The error is occuring because you are comparing a single string `name` to an entire range of cell values -- all of column B. The line should be `If name = active.Range("B" & i).Value Then`

Comment: If name = active.Range("B:B").Value - this doesn't make sense.  Use `FIND` to search for matching values.  See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464631/perform-a-find-within-vba-from-the-bottom-of-a-range-up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I only posted that because your code was unusable in it's current state. You had lines of comments without a `'` so when I copied it, it didn't run, also missing a `"` after `("TRACK` I submitted an edit, looks like you got an answer already, but I was just working on making your code work.

Comment: I agree with @MichalRosa. Use `.Find` Looping to find a value is the inefficient way of doing it if the dataset is large. You may want to see [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try something like this:

```
Sub delete_row()

Dim active As Worksheet
Dim Tracksheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim name As String
Dim cl As Range

Set active = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Active")
Set Tracksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Track")

    With Tracksheet

         For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 4 Step -1

                 name = .Range("B" & i).Value

                    For Each cl In active.Range("B1:B100")

                        If name = cl.Value Then

                            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

                        End If

                    Next cl

                    i = i - 1

        Next i

    End With

 End Sub
```

You can change the Range B1:B100 as per your requirement.

Comment: (You forgot the close quote on `Sheets("Track)`)

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne .... I overlooked the code. Even the setting of worksheet was  wrong!

Comment: No worries! I've also found sometimes simply pasting code to SO helps, since the "coloring" is off if you forget a close parenthesis/quote/etc. That's how I quickly noticed the lack of the closing `"`.

Comment: @BruceWayne ... Great! Learnt something new today :)